# Como funciona a microprogramação?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, microsserviços, princípios-de-programação

Na microprogramação os microprogramas são inscritos em binário e alocados no processador?

Answer (score 4):

> Tradução e adaptação livres de [Uma Breve História da Microprogramação](https://people.computing.clemson.edu/%7Emark/uprog.html) de
> Smotherman, Mark. Publicado pela Universidade de Clemsom, Carolina do
> Sul, EUA

Resumo: A microprogramação é uma técnica para implementar a lógica de controle necessária para executar instruções dentro de um processador. Ele é baseado na ideia geral de buscar microinstruções de baixo nível de um armazenamento de controle e derivar os sinais de controle apropriados para serem ativos em um único ciclo de clock, bem como informações de sequenciamento de microprogramas, de cada microinstrução. Embora as técnicas híbridas sejam agora comuns, a microprogramação é geralmente contrastada com as técnicas de implementação hardwired.

## Definições e Exemplo

Embora o uso solto às vezes equipare o termo "microprogramação" com a ideia de "programar um microcomputador", essa não é a definição padrão. Em vez disso, a microprogramação é uma técnica sistemática para implementar a lógica de controle da unidade central de processamento de um computador. É uma forma de lógica de programa armazenado que substitui os circuitos de controle impresso.

A unidade central de processamento em um sistema de computador é composta por um caminho de dados e uma unidade de controle. O caminho de dados inclui registradores, unidades de função como shifters e ALUs (unidades lógicas e aritméticas), barramentos e caminhos internos do processador e unidades de interface para memória principal e barramentos de E/S. A unidade de controle controla a série de etapas realizadas pelo caminho de dados durante a execução de uma instrução visível ao usuário ou macroinstrução (por exemplo, carregar, adicionar, armazenar).

Cada ação do caminho de dados é chamada de transferência de registro e envolve a transferência de informações dentro do caminho de dados, possivelmente incluindo a transformação de dados, endereços ou bits de instrução pelas unidades de função. Uma transferência de registrador é realizada enviando o conteúdo do registrador para os barramentos internos do processador, selecionando a operação de ALUs, shifters, etc., através dos quais essas informações podem passar e recebendo novos valores para um ou mais registradores.

Os sinais de habilitação de registradores, que controlam o envio ou recebimento de dados nos registradores, e os sinais de seleção de operação, que controlam as ações das unidades funcionais, são chamados de sinais de controle. Esses sinais são fornecidos pela unidade de controle. As coleções de portas lógicas no caminho de dados que respondem a sinais de habilitação e permitem o envio ou recebimento de dados nos registradores são chamadas de pontos de controle.

Cada passo na execução de uma macroinstrução consiste, assim, em uma ou mais transferências de registro, e uma macroinstrução completa é executada gerando uma sequência apropriadamente temporizada de grupos de sinais de controle. Ações nos caminhos de dados individuais ou em seu conjunto são frequentemente chamadas de microoperações.

Como exemplo, considere a unidade de processamento simples na Figura 1. Esse caminho de dados suporta um conjunto de instruções baseado em acumulador de quatro macroinstruções (carregar, adicionar, armazenar e ramificação condicional). O acumulador (ACC) e o contador de programa (PC) são visíveis para o programador em nível de macroinstrução, mas os outros registradores não.
[image: Figura 1. Caminho de dados simples para um computador de quatro instruções (os pequenos círculos representam pontos de controle)]
<sup>Figura 1. Caminho de dados simples para um computador de quatro instruções (os pequenos círculos representam pontos de controle)</sup>

As definições das quatro macroinstruções são dadas na Figura 2, e as definições dos sinais de controle usados ​​para este caminho de dados são dadas na Figura 3. Neste caminho de dados, sinais de controle como `ACC_in` e `ACC_out` são sinais de habilitação de registro e sinais de controle como como `aluadd` e `pcincr` são sinais de seleção de operação.

```
(opcode 00)  load  endereço :   ACC <- memoria[ endereço]

(opcode 01)  add   endereço :   ACC <- ACC + memoria[ endereço]

(opcode 10)  store endereço :   memoria[ endereço] <- ACC

(opcode 11)  brz   endereço :   if( ACC == 0 ) PC <- endereço
```

<sup>Figura 2. Definições de instruções para o computador simples</sup>

```
ACC_in   : ACC <- CPU barramento interno
ACC_out  : CPU barramento interno <- ACC
aluadd   : adição é selecionada como operação ALU
IR_in    : IR <- CPU barramento interno
IR_out   : CPU barramento interno <- porção de endereçamento do IR
MAR_in   : MAR <- CPU barramento interno
MDR_in   : MDR <- CPU barramento interno
MDR_out  : CPU barramento interno <- MDR
PC_in    : PC <- CPU barramento interno
PC_out   : CPU barramento interno <- PC
pcincr   : PC <- PC + 1
read     : MDR <- memoria[ MAR ]
TEMP_out : CPU barramento interno <- TEMP
write    : memoria[ MAR ] <- MDR
```

<sup>Figura 3. Definições de sinal de controle para o caminho de dados simples</sup>

Para implementar o processamento de uma macroinstrução neste caminho de dados, um primeiro grupo de sinais de controle é necessário para buscar a macroinstrução na memória. Esses sinais de controle irão colocar o conteúdo do contador de programa no barramento interno e transportar esses bits do barramento interno para o registrador de endereço de memória. Tanto neste grupo de sinais de controle (ou seja, durante o primeira etapa de tempo) ou no próximo, o contador de programa deve ser incrementado, e a interface de memória deve receber um sinal para causar uma leitura de memória. Após a conclusão da leitura da memória (que pode ser um evento síncrono ou assíncrono), o conteúdo do registrador de dados da memória é transferido para o registrador de instrução.

Uma vez que os bits da macroinstrução estão no registrador de instrução, os bits no campo opcode podem ser usados ​​para controlar as etapas restantes. Essas etapas incluem buscar quaisquer operandos, executar a função especificada pelo opcode e armazenar quaisquer resultados. O processamento total de uma macroinstrução simples pode exigir de cinco a dez etapas de tempo nesse caminho de dados e pode envolver uma dúzia ou mais de sinais de controle.

A Figura 4 apresenta as sequências de controle para as quatro macroinstruções. Para este exemplo simples, supõe-se que uma leitura ou gravação na memória seja concluída em uma etapa de tempo. *Em geral, uma etapa de tempo pode corresponder a um único ciclo de clock, mas o processador pode aumentar qualquer etapa de tempo que exija acesso à memória para fornecer tempo suficiente para que o acesso à memória seja concluído*.

```
etapas de tempo T0-T3 para cada busca de instrução:

        T0: PC_out, MAR_in
        T1: read, pcincr
        T2: MDR_out, IR_in
        T3: time step (if needed) for decoding the opcode in the IR


etapas de tempo T4-T6 para a instrução de carga:

        T4: IR_out(addr part), MAR_in
        T5: read
        T6: MDR_out, ACC_in, reset to T0


etapas de tempo T4-T7 para a instrução de adição:

        T4: IR_out(addr part), MAR_in
        T5: read
        T6: ACC_out, aluadd
        T7: TEMP_out, ACC_in, reset to T0


etapas de tempo T4-T6 para a instrução de armazenamento:

        T4: IR_out(addr part), MAR_in
        T5: ACC_out, MDR_in
        T6: write, reset to T0


etapas de tempo T4-T5 para a instrução brz(desvio em zero):

        T4: if (acceq0) then { IR_out(addr part), PC_in }
        T5: reset to T0
```

<sup>Figura 4. Sequências de controle para as quatro instruções</sup>

Como dito acima, a unidade de controle é responsável por gerar as sequências de sinais de controle. Conforme mostrado no canto inferior esquerdo da Figura 1, as entradas da unidade de controle consistem em

1. um conjunto mutuamente exclusivo de sinais de etapa de tempo,
2. um conjunto mutuamente exclusivo de sinais de opcode decodificados, e
3. sinais de condição usados ​​para implementar a instrução de desvio condicional.

A expressão lógica para um sinal de controle individual pode ser escrita na forma de soma de produtos em que os termos consistem tipicamente em um dado sinal de etapa de tempo e com um sinal de opcode identificando um opcode de instrução específico. No entanto, um determinado termo também pode consistir apenas em um sinal de etapa de tempo, ou pode ter um ou mais dos sinais de condição incluídos. O sinal de controle será então afirmado quando necessário em uma ou mais etapas de tempo específicas durante a busca e execução da instrução.

As expressões lógicas para os sinais de controle para o exemplo simples são fornecidas na Figura 5. Por exemplo, a expressão lógica para `ACC_in` tem a forma típica e é avaliada como verdadeira para a instrução `load` na etapa de tempo `T6` e para a instrução `add` na etapa de tempo `T7`. `IR_in` tem uma expressão simples e é avaliada como verdadeira para todas as instruções na etapa de tempo `T2`. `PC_in` é condicionalmente verdadeiro na etapa de tempo `T4` para a instrução `brz`, uma vez que o sinal de condição `acceq0` é incluído como parte do termo.

```
ACC_in = (load & T6) + (add & T7)
ACC_out = (store & T5) + (add & T6)
aluadd = add & T6
IR_in = T2
IR_out(addr part) = (load & T4) + (add & T4) + (store & T4) + (brz & acceq0 & T4)
MAR_in = T0 + (load & T4) + (add & T4) + (store & T4)
MDR_in = store & T5
MDR_out = T2 + (load & T6)
PC_in = brz & acceq0 & T4
PC_out = T0
pcincr = T1
read = T1 + (load & T5) + (add & T5)
TEMP_out = add & T7
write = store & T6
```

<sup>Figura 5. Definições de sinal de controle em forma de soma de produtos</sup>

Quando as expressões lógicas para os sinais de controle são implementadas diretamente com portas lógicas individuais ou com uma matriz de portas incompletamente decodificada, como uma matriz lógica programada(PLA), diz-se que a unidade de controle está conectada. Uma implementação direta com portas lógicas está representada na Figura 6. O posicionamento tipicamente irregular de portas lógicas em implementações diretas levou a que essa abordagem fosse descrita como "lógica aleatória".
[image: Figura 6. Implementação de controle impresso para o computador de quatro instruções]
<sup>Figura 6. Implementação de controle impresso para o computador de quatro instruções</sup>

Alternativamente, em uma unidade de controle microprogramada, os sinais de controle que devem ser gerados em uma determinada etapa de tempo são armazenados juntos em uma palavra de controle, que é chamada de microinstrução. A coleção de palavras de controle que implementam uma instrução é chamada de microprogramas, e os microprogramas são armazenados em um elemento de memória chamado armazenamento de controle.

Uma implementação microprogramada de controle para o exemplo simples é apresentada na Figura 7. O armazenamento de controle é uma memória de 16x20 bits. Ele é acessado por um registrador de endereço de armazenamento de controle(CSAR), e a palavra que é buscada é mantida em um registrador de instrução de armazenamento de controle(CSIR). Os sinais de controle necessários para uma dada etapa de tempo são assim fornecidos ao caminho de dados pelo CSIR.
[image: Figura 7. Armazenamento de controle para o computador de quatro instruções(bits de controle de zero não exibidos)]
<sup>Figura 7. Armazenamento de controle para o computador de quatro instruções(bits de controle de zero não exibidos)</sup>

Os primeiros quatorze bits em cada microinstrução na Figura 7 são os sinais de controle de habilitação de registro e seleção de operação usados ​​no caminho de dados da Figura 1. Seis bits adicionais são usados ​​em cada microinstrução na Figura 7 para implementar o sequenciamento.

Esses seis bits incluem um campo de próximo endereço de quatro bits junto com um sinal de substituição de um bit (`branch-via-table`) que faz com que o próximo endereço seja carregado de uma tabela de decodificação separada em vez de usar o campo de próximo endereço. Neste exemplo, a tabela de decodificação é indexada pelo campo opcode de dois bits do registrador de instrução e fornece o endereço do ponto de entrada no armazenamento de controle para o microprograma associado a esse opcode específico.

O sexto bit (`or-address-with-acceq`) é usado para tratar a ramificação condicional permitindo que o sinal de condição acceq0 altere condicionalmente o bit menos significativo no campo de próximo endereço. Isso ocorre quando o campo de próximo endereço na microinstrução termina em 0, de modo que a próxima microinstrução será buscada no endereço que termina em 0 ou no endereço sequencialmente seguinte que termina em 1, dependendo do sinal de condição ser falso ou verdadeiro, respectivamente.

A Figura 8 ilustra o sequenciamento de buscas do armazenamento de controle da Figura 7 para as quatro instruções.

```
ciclo CSAR   sinais de controle 
do 
clock

0     0000    PC_out, MAR_in
1     0010    read, pcincr
2     0011    MDR_out, IR_in
3     0100    branch-via-table (para um dos casos abaixo)


    ou uma instrução load causa um desvio para 0101 do ciclo 4:

4     0101    IR_out(addr part), MAR_in
5     0110    read
6     0111    MDR_out, ACC_in (and jump to 0000)


    ou uma instrução add causa um desvio para 1000 para o ciclo 4:

4     1000    IR_out(addr part), MAR_in
5     1001    read
6     1010    ACC_out, aluadd
7     1011    TEMP_out, ACC_in (salta para 0000)


    ou uma instrução store causa um desvio para 1100 do ciclo 4:

4     1100    IR_out(addr part), MAR_in
5     1101    ACC_out, MDR_in
6     1110    write (and jump to 0000)


    ou uma instrução brz causa um desvio para 1111  do ciclo 4; o devio 
    pode ser retornado caso em que o controle retorna ao início
    da próxima busca de macroinstrução no endereço 0000:

4     1111    or_address_with_acceq0 (yields jump to 0000) 


      ou pode ser uma desvio tomada, caso em que o bit de condição 
      verdadeira modificar o campo de próximo endereço e direcionar o 
      armazenamento de controle de buscar para o ciclo 5 para uma 
      microinstrução que altera o PC:

4     1111    or_address_with_acceq0 (yields jump to 0001) 
5     0001    IR_out(addr part), PC_in (and jump to 0000)
```

<sup>Figura 8. Sequências de busca de armazenamento de controle para as quatro instruções</sup>

Conforme mostrado neste exemplo, em uma unidade de controle microprogramada, a sequência de sinais de controle necessários para a busca e execução de instruções deriva de uma série de buscas do armazenamento de controle, em vez de operações de circuitos hardwired. O resultado é um projeto mais sistemático para controle que permite que mudanças sejam feitas alterando o conteúdo do armazenamento de controle em vez de religar ou ressintetizar circuitos hardwired.

É importante observar que o armazenamento de controle descrito acima usa armazenamento completamente não codificado de sinais de controle. Isso é ineficiente (observe todos os locais zero) e uma implementação real codificaria grupos de sinais de controle. Por exemplo, todos os sinais usados ​​para direcionar o conteúdo dos registradores para o único barramento compartilhado são mutuamente exclusivos e podem ser codificados em um campo. De fato, uma microinstrução típica em um processador comercial consiste em um conjunto de campos codificados de vários tamanhos, em vez de conter um vetor de bits de sinais de controle individuais.

Como as microinstruções e os microprogramas ficam entre o projeto lógico (hardware) e o programa de macroinstruções que está sendo executado (software), às vezes são chamados de firmware . Este termo também está sujeito a uso vago. Ascher Opler o definiu pela primeira vez em um artigo da Datamation de 1967 como o conteúdo de um armazenamento de controle gravável, que pode ser recarregado conforme necessário para especializar a interface do usuário de um computador para uma linguagem de programação ou aplicativo específico [Opl67]. No entanto, no uso geral posterior, o termo passou a significar qualquer tipo de microcódigo, residente em armazenamento de controle somente leitura ou gravável. Mais recentemente, o termo foi ampliado para denotar qualquer coisa residente em ROM, incluindo rotinas de nível de macroinstrução para BIOS, carregadores de inicialização ou aplicativos especializados

Answer (score -2):

[Nesse artigo](https://sites.google.com/site/unicontrolmicro/) pode estar a resposta para tua pergunta, item 3.1

3. Unidade de Controle
   A Unidade de Controle executa três ações básicas intrinsecas, que são a busca, decodificação e execução de instruções. Assim sendo, todo processador, ao iniciar sua operação, realiza uma operação ciclica, tendo como base essas três ações. O tipo de UC depende do tipo de microprocessador envolvido. Ela pode ser vista com uma máquina interna cuja função é o sequenciamento e controle da execução de instruções, via um conjunto de microoperações que transferem dados entre registradores.

3.1. Implementação da Unidade de Controle
Existem basicamente duas maneiras de implementar uma unidade de controle. A primeira delas utiliza uma Unidade de Controle Fixa, que implementa lógica aleatória (hardware control) onde todas as informações para a geração dos sinais de controle são sintetizadas através de um circuito combinacional que é elaborado a partir de informações de macroinstruções. A segunda, utiliza microprogramação. Com microprogramação, podemos dividir a implementação em duas categorias:

- Unidade de Controle Microprogramada
- Unidade de Controle Microprogramável

Ambas utilizam memória de controle, onde são armazenados as sequências de códigos binários - um conjunto de instruções (microprograma). Estes códigos são usados para acionar apropriadamente os sinais de controle. A diferença entre as duas categorias está no tipo de memória utilizada para armazenamento das instruções. A Unidade de Controle Microprogramada utiliza a memória ROM (Read Only Memory) como meio de armazenameto do mircroprograma, sendo desta forma o microprograma se encontra gravado no dispositivo de armazenamento. Já a Unidade de Controle Microprogramável utiliza a memória RAM (Random Acess Memory), na qual o microprograma é carregado ou definido toda vez que a máquina é ligada